# Getting 403 with posting to my wall on facebook using API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created an app on facebook and given it following permissions in the required field.

[image: Facebook app permissions]

Now I am trying to Post title and Link. This gives me an error

> {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission}

Any help in this regard will be of much help. The app is still in development mode and I am the admin to the app on Facebook.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with Xamarin. Also, the error message looks pretty clear to me. Check if your Facebook app configuration has those permissions

Comment: the screenshot only shows that you added some permissions to the review process for later, that´s completely irrelevant for testing. do you actually ask for the permissions in your login process?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: Yes I do get ask for the required permissions and checking the available permissions it has everything that are required.

Answer (score 1):

Effective August 1st, 2018, the Facebook API no longer supports the ***publish_actions*** permission, effectively preventing any third-party application from posting on a user's behalf.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/07/31/platform-update-publish-permission/